# Saving Java enums in OrientDB

Tags: java, enums, orientdb

I'm using OrientDB and I would like to save an enum in a field. Something like:

```
db.save(new ODocument("Car").field("color", Colors.BLUE));
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Cannot serialize the object since it's not implements the OSerializableStream interface
```

The easy way to solve this would be to make the "color" property a `String` and then save it like `Colors.BLUE.name()` but if that was the case then I'm pretty sure there should be some way for Orient to handle this for me or, even better, some kind of `OType` that handles this in a more efficient way.

Does anyone know what's the better approach to working with enums?

Comment: what is the version did you use??

Comment: @ILLA I'm using version 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Register a custom serializer for the type - looks like you need to create an OObjectSerializer for that, and register it with the OObjectSerializerContext.

Comment: Are you using your own enum called Colors or did you mistype Color ?If you are not using your own enum, then I guess you would not want to serialize the Color.BLUE by name anyway - the important info is the RGB constituents as you could then save (and unserialize again) any color. Otherwise you would be stuck with just the few having actual names.